# Comparing dictionaries on shared keys only

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries with some shared keys, and some different ones. (Each dictionary has some keys not present in the other). What's a nice way to compare the two dictionaries for equality, as if only the shared keys were present?

In other words I want a simplest way to calculate the following:

```
commonkeys = set(dict1).intersection(dict2)
simple1 = dict((k, v) for k,v in dict1.items() if k in commonkeys)
simple2 = dict((k, v) for k,v in dict2.items() if k in commonkeys)
return simple1 == simple2
```

I've managed to simplify it to this:

```
commonkeys = set(dict1).intersection(dict2)
return all(dict1[key] == dict2[key] for key in commonkeys)
```

But I'm hoping for an approach that doesn't require precalculation of the common keys. (In reality I have two lists of dictionaries that I'll be comparing pairwise. All dictionaries in each list have the same set of keys, so if a computation like `commonkeys` above is necessary, it would only need to be done once.)

Comment: Couldn't you just use `return all(dict1[i] == dict2[i] for i in commonkeys)`?

Comment: Yeah I can-- I was just editing it in. But I'm hoping there's an even better way.

Comment: "I have managed to simplify this"? I don't care, but don't do this to other people ^^

Comment: If you meant I took your suggestion without attribution: No I didn't; I was editing my answer and only saw it afterwards. But I did waste your time by not having it there from the start. My bad. (I'd still upvote it if it was an answer, anyway.)

Comment: No problem. As I said: I don't care.

Answer (score 3):

What about the following?

```
return all(dict2[key] == val for key, val in dict1.iteritems() if key in dict2)
```

Or even shorter (although it possibly involves a few more comparisons):

```
return all(dict2.get(key, val) == val for key, val in dict1.iteritems())
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second version will return `False` as soon as it comes to a key that is in `dict1` but not in `dict2`.

Comment: Try it out then :)

For keys that are in `dict1` AND in `dict2`  [`dict2.get(key, val)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) will return `dict2[key]`, for keys that are in `dict1` AND NOT int `dict2` it will return `val` which obviously it equal to itself.

Comment: Oh NOW I see it. Sneaky!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dict((k, dict1[k]) for k in dict1.keys() + dict2.keys() if dict1.get(k) == dict2.get(k))
```

O(m + n) comparisons.

If you want a true/false result put a simple check on the above result. If not none return true

Comment: I'm not sure how you propose to use this as an equality check.

Comment: try `return all(dict((k, dict1[k]) for k in dict1.keys() + dict2.keys() if dict1.get(k) == dict2.get(k)))`